# Table formatting issues

Tags: tables, formatting

I am new to LaTeX and I am having trouble formatting my table to fit nicely onto the page. It does not have to all fit onto one page length wise just width wise. Thank you for the help!

```
   \documentclass[12pt]{article}
 \begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
\caption{Add caption}
\begin{tabular}{rrrrrr}
      & Volumetric Flow Rate &       &       &       &  \\
      & 0.5   & 1     & 2     & 4     & 7 \\
Inlet Temperature of CO2 & Temperature Out (K) &       &       &       &  \\
300   & 316.5756 & 330.8846 & 354.4685 & 388.5297 & 421.5222 \\
310   & 326.242 & 340.2358 & 363.2396 & 396.3133 & 428.1589 \\
320   & 335.8769 & 349.5299 & 371.915 & 403.956 & 434.6271 \\
330   & 345.4811 & 358.7685 & 380.4977 & 411.4632 & 440.9348 \\
340   & 355.0554 & 367.953 & 388.9905 & 418.8401 & 447.0894 \\
350   & 364.6004 & 377.0847 & 397.3961 & 426.0915 & 453.0977 \\
360   & 374.1168 & 386.1649 & 405.7168 & 433.2217 & 458.9662 \\
370   & 383.6052 & 395.1947 & 413.955 & 440.235 & 464.7007 \\
380   & 393.0659 & 404.1751 & 422.1128 & 447.1352 & 470.307 \\
390   & 402.4995 & 413.1071 & 430.192 & 453.926 & 475.7901 \\
400   & 411.9064 & 421.9917 & 438.1945 & 460.6108 & 481.155 \\
410   & 421.287 & 430.8295 & 446.1222 & 467.1929 & 486.4062 \\
420   & 430.6416 & 439.6214 & 453.9764 & 473.6752 & 491.548 \\
430   & 439.9706 & 448.3681 & 461.7589 & 480.0607 & 496.5844 \\
440   & 449.2742 & 457.0703 & 469.471 & 486.3521 & 501.5193 \\
450   & 458.5527 & 465.7285 & 477.1141 & 492.552 & 506.3562 \\
460   & 467.8064 & 474.3432 & 484.6895 & 498.6628 & 511.0985 \\
470   & 477.0354 & 482.9152 & 492.1983 & 504.6868 & 515.7494 \\
480   & 486.2399 & 491.4447 & 499.6417 & 510.6262 & 520.3119 \\
490   & 495.4202 & 499.9323 & 507.0208 & 516.4832 & 524.789 \\
500   & 504.5763 & 508.3785 & 514.3367 & 522.2597 & 529.1833 \\
510   & 513.7085 & 516.7835 & 521.5902 & 527.9577 & 533.4975 \\
520   & 522.8169 & 525.1478 & 528.7825 & 533.5791 & 537.7339 \\
530   & 531.9015 & 533.4718 & 535.9143 & 539.1254 & 541.895 \\
540   & 540.9625 & 541.7558 & 542.9865 & 544.5985 & 545.983 \\
550   & 550   & 550   & 550   & 550   & 550 \\
560   & 559.014 & 558.2048 & 556.9555 & 555.3314 & 553.9481 \\
570   & 568.0047 & 566.3705 & 563.8539 & 560.5941 & 557.8291 \\
580   & 576.9721 & 574.4973 & 570.6958 & 565.7897 & 561.645 \\
590   & 585.9163 & 582.5855 & 577.482 & 570.9195 & 565.3976 \\
600   & 594.8372 & 590.6354 & 584.2132 & 575.9848 & 569.0885 \\
610   & 603.735 & 598.6471 & 590.89 & 580.987 & 572.7194 \\
620   & 612.6098 & 606.6209 & 597.5131 & 585.9272 & 576.2918 \\

630   & 621.4615 & 614.557 & 604.0831 & 590.8068 & 579.8073 \\
640   & 630.2902 & 622.4556 & 610.6006 & 595.6267 & 583.2674 \\
650   & 639.0959 & 630.3169 & 617.0662 & 600.3882 & 586.6733 \\
660   & 647.8786 & 638.1411 & 623.4806 & 605.0924 & 590.0265 \\
670   & 656.6385 & 645.9285 & 629.8442 & 609.7403 & 593.3282 \\
680   & 665.3754 & 653.6791 & 636.1577 & 614.3329 & 596.5797 \\
690   & 674.0895 & 661.3933 & 642.4215 & 618.8713 & 599.7823 \\
700   & 682.7807 & 669.071 & 648.6363 & 623.3563 & 602.9369 \\
710   & 691.4491 & 676.7127 & 654.8025 & 627.7891 & 606.0449 \\
720   & 700.0947 & 684.3184 & 660.9207 & 632.1705 & 609.1072 \\
730   & 708.7176 & 691.8883 & 666.9913 & 636.5013 & 612.1249 \\
740   & 717.3177 & 699.4225 & 673.015 & 640.7825 & 615.099 \\
750   & 725.8952 & 706.9214 & 678.9921 & 645.0149 & 618.0305 \\
760   & 734.4499 & 714.385 & 684.9232 & 649.1994 & 620.9204 \\
770   & 742.9821 & 721.8135 & 690.8087 & 653.3368 & 623.7695 \\
780   & 751.4916 & 729.2072 & 696.6492 & 657.4278 & 626.5788 \\
790   & 759.9785 & 736.5661 & 702.4451 & 661.4733 & 629.3492 \\
800   & 768.443 & 743.8906 & 708.1968 & 665.474 & 632.0814 \\
810   & 776.885 & 751.1807 & 713.9049 & 669.4306 & 634.7763 \\
820   & 785.3045 & 758.4367 & 719.5699 & 673.344 & 637.4347 \\
830   & 793.7017 & 765.6587 & 725.1921 & 677.2148 & 640.0573 \\
840   & 802.0766 & 772.8471 & 730.772 & 681.0437 & 642.645 \\
850   & 810.4292 & 780.0019 & 736.3102 & 684.8314 & 645.1984 \\
860   & 818.7596 & 787.1233 & 741.8069 & 688.5786 & 647.7183 \\
870   & 827.0679 & 794.2117 & 747.2628 & 692.286 & 650.2053 \\
880   & 835.3542 & 801.2672 & 752.6783 & 695.9542 & 652.6602 \\
890   & 843.6185 & 808.29 & 758.0537 & 699.5838 & 655.0836 \\
900   & 851.861 & 815.2803 & 763.3896 & 703.1756 & 657.4761 \\
910   & 860.0817 & 822.2384 & 768.6863 & 706.7301 & 659.8384 \\
920   & 868.2807 & 829.1646 & 773.9444 & 710.2479 & 662.171 \\
930   & 876.4582 & 836.0589 & 779.1643 & 713.7296 & 664.4747 \\
940   & 884.6142 & 842.9218 & 784.3465 & 717.1759 & 666.7499 \\
950   & 892.7489 & 849.7534 & 789.4913 & 720.5874 & 668.9973 \\
960   & 900.8623 & 856.554 & 794.5992 & 723.9645 & 671.2174 \\
970   & 908.9547 & 863.3238 & 799.6707 & 727.3079 & 673.4108 \\
980   & 917.0261 & 870.0632 & 804.7062 & 730.6182 & 675.578 \\
990   & 925.0767 & 876.7723 & 809.7062 & 733.8958 & 677.7195 \\
1000  & 933.1067 & 883.4515 & 814.6711 & 737.1414 & 679.8359 \\
\end{tabular}%
\label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The name of the game is `LaTeX`, not `LaTeK` ;-) And you might benefit from the `longtable` package

Comment: Ah! I will be sure to change that now! I took a look at that but i was still having trouble.

Comment: Try to change each  `r`column with some like `p{60pt}` and search about the use of  `tabularx`,  `tabulary` and `booktabs` packages

Comment: Aside: What is the significance of reporting output degrees to `10^{-4}K` accuracy if the input degrees are reported only to within `10^{-0}K` accuracy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having long column headers is your main problem, replacing  those with symbols that are explained in the caption, such as `$T_{\mathrm{in}}$` for the inlet temperature, helps a lot.

This is probably not exactly what you want, but it should give you an idea. If there is anything in particular you want, add a comment

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{l *{5}{S}}
\caption{$T_{\mathrm{in}}$ and $T_{\mathrm{out}}$ are inlet and outlet temperature, respectively.\label{tab:addlabel}} \\
\toprule
      & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Volumetric Flow Rate} \\
      & 0.5   & 1     & 2     & 4     & 7 \\ \midrule
$T_{\mathrm{in}}$ [K] & $T_{\mathrm{out}}$ [K]  &       &       &       &  \\ \midrule
300   & 316.5756 & 330.8846 & 354.4685 & 388.5297 & 421.5222 \\
310   & 326.242 & 340.2358 & 363.2396 & 396.3133 & 428.1589 \\
320   & 335.8769 & 349.5299 & 371.915 & 403.956 & 434.6271 \\
330   & 345.4811 & 358.7685 & 380.4977 & 411.4632 & 440.9348 \\
340   & 355.0554 & 367.953 & 388.9905 & 418.8401 & 447.0894 \\
350   & 364.6004 & 377.0847 & 397.3961 & 426.0915 & 453.0977 \\
360   & 374.1168 & 386.1649 & 405.7168 & 433.2217 & 458.9662 \\
370   & 383.6052 & 395.1947 & 413.955 & 440.235 & 464.7007 \\
380   & 393.0659 & 404.1751 & 422.1128 & 447.1352 & 470.307 \\
390   & 402.4995 & 413.1071 & 430.192 & 453.926 & 475.7901 \\
400   & 411.9064 & 421.9917 & 438.1945 & 460.6108 & 481.155 \\
410   & 421.287 & 430.8295 & 446.1222 & 467.1929 & 486.4062 \\
420   & 430.6416 & 439.6214 & 453.9764 & 473.6752 & 491.548 \\
430   & 439.9706 & 448.3681 & 461.7589 & 480.0607 & 496.5844 \\
440   & 449.2742 & 457.0703 & 469.471 & 486.3521 & 501.5193 \\
450   & 458.5527 & 465.7285 & 477.1141 & 492.552 & 506.3562 \\
460   & 467.8064 & 474.3432 & 484.6895 & 498.6628 & 511.0985 \\
470   & 477.0354 & 482.9152 & 492.1983 & 504.6868 & 515.7494 \\
480   & 486.2399 & 491.4447 & 499.6417 & 510.6262 & 520.3119 \\
490   & 495.4202 & 499.9323 & 507.0208 & 516.4832 & 524.789 \\
500   & 504.5763 & 508.3785 & 514.3367 & 522.2597 & 529.1833 \\
510   & 513.7085 & 516.7835 & 521.5902 & 527.9577 & 533.4975 \\
520   & 522.8169 & 525.1478 & 528.7825 & 533.5791 & 537.7339 \\
530   & 531.9015 & 533.4718 & 535.9143 & 539.1254 & 541.895 \\
540   & 540.9625 & 541.7558 & 542.9865 & 544.5985 & 545.983 \\
550   & 550   & 550   & 550   & 550   & 550 \\
560   & 559.014 & 558.2048 & 556.9555 & 555.3314 & 553.9481 \\
570   & 568.0047 & 566.3705 & 563.8539 & 560.5941 & 557.8291 \\
580   & 576.9721 & 574.4973 & 570.6958 & 565.7897 & 561.645 \\
590   & 585.9163 & 582.5855 & 577.482 & 570.9195 & 565.3976 \\
600   & 594.8372 & 590.6354 & 584.2132 & 575.9848 & 569.0885 \\
610   & 603.735 & 598.6471 & 590.89 & 580.987 & 572.7194 \\
620   & 612.6098 & 606.6209 & 597.5131 & 585.9272 & 576.2918 \\
630   & 621.4615 & 614.557 & 604.0831 & 590.8068 & 579.8073 \\
640   & 630.2902 & 622.4556 & 610.6006 & 595.6267 & 583.2674 \\
650   & 639.0959 & 630.3169 & 617.0662 & 600.3882 & 586.6733 \\
660   & 647.8786 & 638.1411 & 623.4806 & 605.0924 & 590.0265 \\
670   & 656.6385 & 645.9285 & 629.8442 & 609.7403 & 593.3282 \\
680   & 665.3754 & 653.6791 & 636.1577 & 614.3329 & 596.5797 \\
690   & 674.0895 & 661.3933 & 642.4215 & 618.8713 & 599.7823 \\
700   & 682.7807 & 669.071 & 648.6363 & 623.3563 & 602.9369 \\
710   & 691.4491 & 676.7127 & 654.8025 & 627.7891 & 606.0449 \\
720   & 700.0947 & 684.3184 & 660.9207 & 632.1705 & 609.1072 \\
730   & 708.7176 & 691.8883 & 666.9913 & 636.5013 & 612.1249 \\
740   & 717.3177 & 699.4225 & 673.015 & 640.7825 & 615.099 \\
750   & 725.8952 & 706.9214 & 678.9921 & 645.0149 & 618.0305 \\
760   & 734.4499 & 714.385 & 684.9232 & 649.1994 & 620.9204 \\
770   & 742.9821 & 721.8135 & 690.8087 & 653.3368 & 623.7695 \\
780   & 751.4916 & 729.2072 & 696.6492 & 657.4278 & 626.5788 \\
790   & 759.9785 & 736.5661 & 702.4451 & 661.4733 & 629.3492 \\
800   & 768.443 & 743.8906 & 708.1968 & 665.474 & 632.0814 \\
810   & 776.885 & 751.1807 & 713.9049 & 669.4306 & 634.7763 \\
820   & 785.3045 & 758.4367 & 719.5699 & 673.344 & 637.4347 \\
830   & 793.7017 & 765.6587 & 725.1921 & 677.2148 & 640.0573 \\
840   & 802.0766 & 772.8471 & 730.772 & 681.0437 & 642.645 \\
850   & 810.4292 & 780.0019 & 736.3102 & 684.8314 & 645.1984 \\
860   & 818.7596 & 787.1233 & 741.8069 & 688.5786 & 647.7183 \\
870   & 827.0679 & 794.2117 & 747.2628 & 692.286 & 650.2053 \\
880   & 835.3542 & 801.2672 & 752.6783 & 695.9542 & 652.6602 \\
890   & 843.6185 & 808.29 & 758.0537 & 699.5838 & 655.0836 \\
900   & 851.861 & 815.2803 & 763.3896 & 703.1756 & 657.4761 \\
910   & 860.0817 & 822.2384 & 768.6863 & 706.7301 & 659.8384 \\
920   & 868.2807 & 829.1646 & 773.9444 & 710.2479 & 662.171 \\
930   & 876.4582 & 836.0589 & 779.1643 & 713.7296 & 664.4747 \\
940   & 884.6142 & 842.9218 & 784.3465 & 717.1759 & 666.7499 \\
950   & 892.7489 & 849.7534 & 789.4913 & 720.5874 & 668.9973 \\
960   & 900.8623 & 856.554 & 794.5992 & 723.9645 & 671.2174 \\
970   & 908.9547 & 863.3238 & 799.6707 & 727.3079 & 673.4108 \\
980   & 917.0261 & 870.0632 & 804.7062 & 730.6182 & 675.578 \\
990   & 925.0767 & 876.7723 & 809.7062 & 733.8958 & 677.7195 \\
1000  & 933.1067 & 883.4515 & 814.6711 & 737.1414 & 679.8359 \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @TorbjørnT. I made a few edits and it is formatted in a way that works for me.